# ошибка декодинга Json swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode

Появляется ошибка при попытке кодирования кода:

failed to convert typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "rating", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "lesson", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "__v", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

вот мой код:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CardViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let account = UserDefaults.standard
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionCard: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordNumBook: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var faculty: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var groupName: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var averageRating: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingUpdateTime: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        recordNumBook.text = (account.object(forKey: "recordNumBook") as! String)
        faculty.text = (account.object(forKey: "faculty") as! String)
        groupName.text = (account.object(forKey: "groupName") as! String)
        
        let URL = "https://vsuet.app/api/rating/get?recordBookNum=217073"
            print("Продолжить")
        getData(from:URL)
    }
    
    private func getData(from url: String){

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { [self] data, response, error in
            
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
    print("something went wrong")
    return
    }


    var result: RatingProperty?
           
    do {
    result = try JSONDecoder().decode(RatingProperty.self, from: data)
    }
    catch{
    print("failed to convert \(error)")
    }



    guard let json = result else {
    return
    }

            print(json.data)
        var avgRating = 0
    let rating = json.data.rating
        for ratingItem in rating{
            if (ratingItem.value[26] != ""){
                avgRating += Int(ratingItem.value[26]) ?? 0
            }
        
        }
        self.account.set(avgRating, forKey: "averageRating")
            averageRating.text = String(avgRating)
            
            ratingUpdateTime.text = "Рейинг обновлен:" + json.data.student.ratingUpdatedAt
        

    })
        
    task.resume()
    }

    
}
```

структура откуда беру данные:

```
struct RatingProperty : Codable{
let status: Bool
let data: FullRatingData
}


struct FullRatingData : Codable{
let rating: Array<RatingItem>
let student: StudentItem
}

struct StudentItem : Codable{
let _id: String
let recordBookNum: String
let faculty: FacultyItem
let groups: Array<GroupItem>
let ratingUpdatedAt: String
}

struct FacultyItem : Codable{
let _id: String
let createdTime: String
let name: String
let value: String
let __v: String?
}

struct GroupItem : Codable{
let _id: String
let faculty: String
let name: String
let value: String
let __v: String?
}


struct RatingItem : Codable{
let _id: String
let value: Array<String>
let upgradedRating: Array<UpgradedRatingItem>?
let createdTime: String
let student: String
let faculty: String
let group: String
let lesson: RatingLesson
let total: TotalItem
let __v: String?
}

struct TotalItem : Codable{
let premiumRating: PremiumRating
let summaryRating: SummaryRating
let ratingByMark: RatingByMark
let lessonTypeRating: LessonTypeRating
let summary: Summary
}

struct PremiumRating : Codable{
let name: String
let score: String
}

struct SummaryRating : Codable{
let name: String
let score: String
}

struct RatingByMark : Codable{
let name: String
let score: String
}

struct LessonTypeRating : Codable{
let name: String
let score: String
}

struct Summary : Codable{
let name: String
let score: String
}

struct RatingLesson : Codable{
let _id: String
let faculty: String
let group: String
let name: String
let type: String
let __v: String?
let href: String
let isClose: Bool
let header: Array<HeaderItem>
let information: InformationItem
}

struct InformationItem : Codable{
let department: String
let teacher: String
let hours: String
let semester: String
let course: String
let updatedAt: String
}

struct HeaderItem : Codable{
let trIndex: String
let children: Array<HeaderChildrenItem>
}

struct HeaderChildrenItem : Codable{
let text: String
let colSpan: Int
let rowSpan: Int
}

struct UpgradedRatingItem : Codable{
let items: Array<DisciplineInnerPoint>
let total: DisciplineItem
}


struct DisciplineItem : Codable{
let name: String
let score: String
}

struct DisciplineInnerPoint : Codable{
let name: String
let weight: String
let score: String
}
```

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Если перевести ошибку на русский: "Ожидалось декодировать строку, но вместо этого было найдено число", то можно сделать вывод, что вы получаете строку там, где ожидалось число. Пожалуйста, добавьте к вопросу json, который вы парсите. Но даже так уже можно сказать, что, скорее всего, `score: Int`, `id: Int`, `hours: Int` и так далее.

Comment: Не помогает замена на Int

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к вопросу json, который вы парсите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас было несколько ошибок, аналогичных упомянутой, см примечания в коде, кроме того, пришлось сделать ручное декодирование из-за вариаций значений в массиве внутри `RatingItem.value` (пустая строка/строка/число)

```
    private func getData(from url: String){
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { [self] data, response, error in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("something went wrong")
                return
            }
            
            
            var result: RatingProperty?
            
            do {
                result = try JSONDecoder().decode(RatingProperty.self, from: data)
            }
            catch{
                print("failed to convert \(error)")
            }

            guard let json = result else {
                return
            }
            
            print(json.data)
            var avgRating = 0
            let rating = json.data.rating
            
            for ratingItem in rating{ // MARK: fixed
                for item in ratingItem.value {
                    if item != "" {
                        avgRating += Int(item) ?? 0
                    }
                }
            }
            
            self.account.set(avgRating, forKey: "averageRating")
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                averageRating.text = String(avgRating)
                ratingUpdateTime.text = "Рейинг обновлен:" + json.data.student.ratingUpdatedAt
            }
        
        })
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

---

```
struct RatingProperty : Codable{
    let status: Bool
    let data: FullRatingData
}


struct FullRatingData : Codable{
    let rating: Array<RatingItem>
    let student: StudentItem
}

struct StudentItem : Codable{
    let _id: String
    let recordBookNum: String
    let faculty: FacultyItem
    let groups: Array<GroupItem>
    let ratingUpdatedAt: String
}

struct FacultyItem : Codable{
    let _id: String
    let createdTime: String
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    let __v: Int? // MARK: fixed
}

struct GroupItem : Codable{
    let _id: String
    let faculty: String
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    let __v: Int? // MARK: fixed
}


struct RatingItem : Codable{
    let _id: String
    let value: Array<String>
    let upgradedRating: Array<UpgradedRatingItem>?
    let createdTime: String
    let student: String
    let faculty: String
    let group: String
    let lesson: RatingLesson
    let total: TotalItem?
    let __v: Int?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        _id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: ._id)
        
        var valueContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .value)
        var valueItems = [String]()
        
        while !valueContainer.isAtEnd {
            let valueItem = try valueContainer.decode(String.self)
            valueItems.append(valueItem)
        }
        
        value = valueItems // MARK: fixed
        
        upgradedRating = try container.decodeIfPresent(Array<UpgradedRatingItem>.self, forKey: .upgradedRating)
        createdTime = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .createdTime)
        student = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .student)
        faculty = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .faculty)
        group = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .group)
        lesson = try container.decode(RatingLesson.self, forKey: .lesson)
        total = try container.decodeIfPresent(TotalItem.self, forKey: .total)
        __v = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .__v)
    }
}

struct TotalItem : Codable{
    let premiumRating: PremiumRating
    let summaryRating: SummaryRating
    let ratingByMark: RatingByMark
    let lessonTypeRating: LessonTypeRating
    let summary: Summary
}

struct PremiumRating : Codable{
    let name: String
    let score: String
}

struct SummaryRating : Codable{
    let name: String
    let score: String
}

struct RatingByMark : Codable{
    let name: String
    let score: String
}

struct LessonTypeRating : Codable{
    let name: String
    let score: String
}

struct Summary : Codable{
    let name: String
    let score: String
}

struct RatingLesson : Codable{
    let _id: String
    let faculty: String
    let group: String
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let __v: Int? // MARK: fixed
    let href: String
    let isClose: Bool
    let header: Array<HeaderItem>
    let information: InformationItem
}

struct InformationItem : Codable{
    let department: String
    let teacher: String
    let hours: String
    let semester: String
    let course: String
    let updatedAt: String
}

struct HeaderItem : Codable{
    let trIndex: Int // MARK: fixed
    let children: Array<HeaderChildrenItem>
}

struct HeaderChildrenItem : Codable{
    let text: String
    let colSpan: Int
    let rowSpan: Int
}

struct UpgradedRatingItem : Codable{
    let items: Array<DisciplineInnerPoint>
    let total: DisciplineItem
}


struct DisciplineItem : Codable{
    let name: String
    let score: String
}

struct DisciplineInnerPoint : Codable{
    let name: String
    let weight: String
    let score: String
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое за верный ответ